# not all fields are copied from mongodb to solr after integration using mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am able to successfully integrate between MONGODB & SOLR, using MONGO-CONNECTOR. And whenever, I update or add any thing, in the sample collection i have created, it copies only two or three fields in a documents, and rest of the fields data are not copied into solr. This is some thing I am not able to do it.

This is my collection and its document details. Name of collection: `testdb`

document inserted as follows:

```
db.testdb.insert( {
...  _id: "101",
...  name: "test",
...  description: "descr",
...  mydesc: "mydescr",
...  nmdsc: "nmdsc1",
...  coords: "coords1"
...  })

And the data sync between solr and mongo logs says successful:
2014-01-17 19:35:38,462 - INFO - Finished 'http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/update/?co
mmit=true' (post) with body '<add><doc>' in 0.210 seconds.
```

But when I execute a query to see the document data it says only these fields data:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "*:*",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "101",
                "description": "descr",
                "name": "test",
                "_version_": 1457486601392226300
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Clearly i can see that following fields & respective data are not copied into solr:

```
...  mydesc: "mydescr",
...  nmdsc: "nmdsc1",
...  coords: "coords1"
```

Following is my schema.xml:

```
<schema name="narayana" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="text_wslc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate" />
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" />
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="name" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="description" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="mydesc" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="nmdsc" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="coords" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <defaultSearchField>nmdsc</defaultSearchField>
  <!-- we don't want too many results in this usecase -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
  <copyField source="name" dest="nmdsc" />
  <copyField source="description" dest="nmdsc" />
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your configuration to copy only two specific fields, if you want to index additional fields, you should be adding them to your configuration file and the same import cycle again:

```
  <!-- we don't want too many results in this usecase -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
  <copyField source="name" dest="nmdsc" />
  <copyField source="description" dest="nmdsc" />
```